# How to insert an uniqueindentifier into a table using sql server?

Tags: sql, uniqueidentifier

I have already had a table called a which has a column named b. The type of b is uniqueidentifier. I want to insert something into this column.
However, sql statement like:

```
insert into a (b) 
values ('73C9B60E-27E4-4523-82A3-6992312348AE')
```

fails. 
How can I solve the problem? Thank you.

Comment: This seems to be ok for me,Add error message

Comment: "fails" - fails **how**? do you get `0 row(s) inserted`? Or an *error message*? If it's an error, what does it **say**?

Answer (score 0):

A uniqueidentifier is essentially a GUID, so you should format the input like one. 
The format for a GUID is `{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}`. In SQL you can leave out the parenthesis. See [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier#Text_encoding) for more info on GUIDs.

Comment: I already have a guid like '73C9B60E-27E4-4523-82A3-699239A478AE',.How can I insert it ?

Comment: Ok, that wasn't very clear from your question. What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [GUID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) in SQL server as:

```
select newid();
```

> I already have a guid like '73C9B60E-27E4-4523-82A3-699239A478AE',.How can I insert it ?

This was not clear at all from your question... but you could do:

```
create table #test (myGuid uniqueidentifier)

insert into #test (myGuid)
select convert(uniqueidentifier, '73C9B60E-27E4-4523-82A3-699239A478AE')

drop table #test
```

Comment: `aaaaaaa` is not a valid `uniqueidentifier`.  `Uniqueidentifiers` are `uniqueidentifiers`.  you have to insert into column `b` an appropriate type.  `newid()` is a way to get that appropriate type

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the uniqueidentifier, it is not done for you automatically.

```
DECLARE @GUID uniqueidentifier

SET @GUID = NEWID()

INSERT INTO a VALUES (@GUID)
```

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/uniqueidentifier-vs-identity